# Material UI implementation in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am new to typeScript and I am using this materialUI premium theme OnePirate and I am using the Footer component and it is working perfectly fine in the js but when I am moving the same Footer component to my project and rename the component to .tsx It throws errors saying "No Overload matches this call"
Here is the code:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";
import Container from "@material-ui/core/Container";
import Typography from "./materialUi/Typography";
import TextField from "./materialUi/TextField";
import fbicon from "./static/themes/onepirate/appFooterFacebook.png";
import twicon from "./static/themes/onepirate/appFooterTwitter.png";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
  },
  container: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
    marginBottom: theme.spacing(8),
    display: "flex",
  },
  iconsWrapper: {
    height: 120,
  },
  icons: {
    display: "flex",
  },
  icon: {
    width: 48,
    height: 48,
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.warning.main,
    marginRight: theme.spacing(1),
    "&:hover": {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.warning.dark,
    },
  },
  list: {
    margin: 0,
    listStyle: "none",
    paddingLeft: 0,
  },
  listItem: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(0.5),
  },
  language: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 150,
  },
}));

const LANGUAGES = [
  {
    code: "en-US",
    name: "English",
  },
  {
    code: "fr-FR",
    name: "Français",
  },
];

function Footer() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Typography component="footer" className={classes.root}>
      <Container className={classes.container}>
        <Grid container spacing={5}>
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={4} md={3}>
            <Grid
              container
              direction="column"
              justify="flex-end"
              className={classes.iconsWrapper}
              spacing={2}
            >
              <Grid item className={classes.icons}>
                <a href="https://material-ui.com/" className={classes.icon}>
                  <img src={fbicon} alt="Facebook" />
                </a>
                <a
                  href="https://twitter.com/MaterialUI"
                  className={classes.icon}
                >
                  <img src={twicon} alt="Twitter" />
                </a>
              </Grid>
              <Grid item>© 2019 Onepirate</Grid>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={4} md={2}>
            <Typography variant="h6" marked="left" gutterBottom>
              Legal
            </Typography>
            <ul className={classes.list}>
              <li className={classes.listItem}>
                <Link href="/premium-themes/onepirate/terms/">Terms</Link>
              </li>
              <li className={classes.listItem}>
                <Link href="/premium-themes/onepirate/privacy/">Privacy</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={6} sm={8} md={4}>
            <Typography variant="h6" marked="left" gutterBottom>
              Language
            </Typography>
            <TextField
              select
              SelectProps={{
                native: true,
              }}
              className={classes.language}
            >
              {LANGUAGES.map((language) => (
                <option value={language.code} key={language.code}>
                  {language.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </TextField>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item>
            <Typography variant="caption">
              {"Icons made by "}
              <Link
                href="https://www.freepik.com"
                rel="nofollow"
                title="Freepik"
              >
                Freepik
              </Link>
              {" from "}
              <Link
                href="https://www.flaticon.com"
                rel="nofollow"
                title="Flaticon"
              >
                www.flaticon.com
              </Link>
              {" is licensed by "}
              <Link
                href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/"
                title="Creative Commons BY 3.0"
                target="_blank"
                rel="noopener noreferrer"
              >
                CC 3.0 BY
              </Link>
            </Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </Typography>
  );
}
export default Footer;
```

This is the Typography code if I don't import from material UI

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { capitalize } from "@material-ui/core/utils";
import MuiTypography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = (theme) => ({
  markedH2Center: {
    height: 4,
    width: 73,
    display: "block",
    margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  markedH3Center: {
    height: 4,
    width: 55,
    display: "block",
    margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  markedH4Center: {
    height: 4,
    width: 55,
    display: "block",
    margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
  },
  markedH6Left: {
    height: 2,
    width: 28,
    display: "block",
    marginTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
    background: "currentColor",
  },
});

const variantMapping = {
  h1: "h1",
  h2: "h1",
  h3: "h1",
  h4: "h1",
  h5: "h3",
  h6: "h2",
  subtitle1: "h3",
};

function Typography(props) {
  const { children, classes, marked = false, variant, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <MuiTypography variantMapping={variantMapping} variant={variant} {...other}>
      {children}
      {marked ? (
        <span
          className={
            classes[`marked${capitalize(variant) + capitalize(marked)}`]
          }
        />
      ) : null}
    </MuiTypography>
  );
}

Typography.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  marked: PropTypes.oneOf([false, "center", "left"]),
  variant: PropTypes.string,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Typography);
```

This is the error now: [image: This is the error if i use the typography file]

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. There is no `marked` property in `Typography` component.

Comment: @MezbaulHaque see the edited version. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: I've open sourced my implementation of onepirate in Typescript so you can just use that: https://github.com/rothbart/onepirate-typescript

This is a great question. Onepirate is a great resource but as you've noticed it isn't really built in a way that's Typescript friendly.

Your problem here is that the Typography implementation in onepirate isn't doing a great job of specifying which properties it expects, and is relying on the fact that vanilla JS will mostly just pass everything through to the underlying MuiTypography component.

Here's a much cleaner Typography implementation that preserves the underline effect in onepirate works with Typescript:

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes, { InferProps } from "prop-types";
import {
  withStyles,
  WithStyles,
  createStyles,
  Theme,
} from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import MuiTypography, { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const styles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    markedH2Center: {
      height: 4,
      width: 73,
      display: "block",
      margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    markedH3Center: {
      height: 4,
      width: 55,
      display: "block",
      margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    markedH4Center: {
      height: 4,
      width: 55,
      display: "block",
      margin: `${theme.spacing(1)}px auto 0`,
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.main,
    },
    markedH6Left: {
      height: 2,
      width: 28,
      display: "block",
      marginTop: theme.spacing(0.5),
      background: "currentColor",
    },
  });

function getMarkedClassName(variant: string) {
  switch (variant) {
    case "h2":
      return "markedH2Center";
    case "h3":
      return "markedH3Center";
    case "h4":
      return "markedH4Center";
  }
  return "markedH6Left";
}

const variantMapping = {
  h1: "h1",
  h2: "h1",
  h3: "h1",
  h4: "h1",
  h5: "h3",
  h6: "h2",
  subtitle1: "h3",
};

function Typography<C extends React.ElementType>(
  props: TypographyProps<C, { component?: C }> &
    WithStyles<typeof styles> &
    InferProps<typeof Typography.propTypes>
) {
  const { children, variant, classes, marked, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <MuiTypography variantMapping={variantMapping} variant={variant} {...other}>
      {children}
      {marked ? (
        <span className={classes[getMarkedClassName(variant as string)]} />
      ) : null}
    </MuiTypography>
  );
}

Typography.propTypes = {
  marked: PropTypes.oneOf([false, "center", "left"]),
};

Typography.defaultProps = {
  marked: false,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(Typography);
```

Just a heads up that will run into this same problem with other onepirate components as well (I just finished re-implementing most of them in Typescript so I could use them in my own web app). If you're trying to reverse engineer how I did this I'd pay particular attention to how I took advantage of MuiTypography props and then just added the one new property I needed (**marked**).

```
TypographyProps<C, { component?: C }> &
    WithStyles<typeof styles> &
    InferProps<typeof Typography.propTypes>
```

I'd also **highly recommend** reading over https://material-ui.com/guides/typescript/ if you haven't already, it's a super helpful guide for understanding some of the Typescript gotchas in Material-UI.